# How to make animated search box with search and close icon in CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

I am wondering how can we make an animated search box with search icon and a close icon. When someone clicks on search icon, the search box expands smoothly and clicking on close icon will collapse it. One thing more when we type some text in it then clicking on search icon will submit the search form. A very good example can be seen [here](https://nest.com/).

Both solutions - CSS and jQuery are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a very nice example, hope it will be useful.

http://icanbecreative.com/article/css3-animated-search-box/

Comment: I had already seen it few days ago. But actually I wanted exactly the same as I saw in my given example.